# How to add many values in error-bars chart in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Anyone can help me, please?

```
x = np.array([['A','B','C','D','E'],['A','B','C','D','E']])
y = np.array([[2.60, 3.04, 2.98, 3.76, 3.00],[2.68, 2.96, 2.94, 3.75,3.03]])
yerr = np.array([[1.26, 1.37, 1.33 , 1.27, 1.38],[ 1.25, 1.38, 1.31, 1.27,1.38 ]])
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, fmt='o')
```

I am trying to plot error-bars with many values but the Python extracted the errors that

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

although `matplotlib.pyplot` allows to draw error-bar with array data?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

parameters x and y should be one dimensional array, try to modify like this

```
x = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E'])
y = np.array([2.60, 3.04, 2.98, 3.76, 3.00])
yerr = np.array([[1.26, 1.37, 1.33 , 1.27, 1.38],[ 1.25, 1.38, 1.31, 1.27,1.38 ]]) 
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, fmt='o')
```